# background repeat-y but not below page

Tags: html, css

I have a background image which i need to display vertically as long as the content on the page, but, my background image only shows to the page in view and when I scroll down for the rest of the content the background is not shown in the rest of the page. What am I doing wrong?

css for the background image

```
#wrapper {
text-align: left;
margin: 0px auto;
border:0;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('/images_/backgrounds/content_shadow.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: If you could post an example link, that would help.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar I can't i'm afraid, on dev server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the height property, the 100% is relative to what?
Generally i prefer defining height rules with min-height.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the background-image and background-repeat rules to body instead of #wrapper.

Comment: He only wants it for the "content" of the page.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar correct, I have another image in the body

Comment: Oh ok. Well height:100% doesn't produce the result you might think. It usually doesn't expand the element at all. Instead of height:100% try min-height:100%.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the wrapper div isn't extending to the bottom of the content either.  Try setting the border of wrapper to:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

You might find that the background is behaving just fine, and the div isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background image styling to html{ } instead.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `height: 100%;` from css.